# Race condition from long running task firing update events

Tags: c#, events, concurrency, task-parallel-library, race-condition

My goal is to implement a concurrent method using event based asynchronous programming (EBAP) model, to handle status changes on a viewmodel. I have a long running task that is queued from the UI thread, using a `RunNextItem` method on a viewmodel class that looks like the `DemoViewModel` class below.

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
    private DemoRunClass DemoRunner;
    private ItemViewModel _currentlyRunningItem;

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute long running task on another thread.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task RunNextItem()
    {
        // get viewmodel of next item and create a command for it.
        var nextRunnableItemViewModel = GetNextItem();
        var runItemCommand = GenerateCommand(nextRunnableItemViewModel);

        // store the current item in local variable
        _currentlyRunningItem = nextRunnableItemViewModel;

        try
        {
            await DemoRunner.ExecuteLongRunningTask(
                runItemCommand, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { ... }
        finally
        {
            // clear local variable
            _currentlyRunningItem = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle updates from DemoRunner class
    /// </summary>
    private void OnUpdateEvent(object status)
    {
        if (status == "Method1 complete")
            _curentlyRunningItem.OnMethod1Complete();
        // ...
        else if (status == "All Complete")
            _curentlyRunningItem.OnAllComplete();
    }
}
```

The class that implements the long running task looks like:

```
public class DemoRunClass
{
    public event EventHandler<object> ExecutionUpdate;
    public Dispatcher EventDispatcher;

    public Task ExecuteLongRunningTask(object command, Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        EventDispatcher = dispatcher; // store dispatcher from UI thread

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Method1(); // call UpdateEvent(method 1 complete)
            Method2(); // call UpdateEvent(method 2 complete).. etc
            Method3();
            Method4();
            Method5();
            UpdateEvent("All Complete");
        });
    }

    public void UpdateEvent(object status)
    {
        if (!EventDispatcher.CheckAccess())
            EventDispatcher.Invoke(new Action<object>(UpdateEvent), status);
        else
        {
            ExecutionUpdate?.Invoke(null, status);
        }
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        // do some work ..
        UpdateEvent("Method1 complete");
    }

    // ... 
}
```

The idea is that the `DemoViewModel` class stores a local instance of the `ItemViewModel` of the object that is to be "run". The execution of the "run" is handled in the `DemoRunClass` which simply executes a number of methods, each of which will raise an event to signal the progress/status of the task. When it is complete, it fires the same event again with a "Complete" status. The task is awaited by the `DemoViewModel`, after which it sets the `_currentlyRunningItem` field to null;

The event handler in `DemoViewModel` handles these status events and updates the `_currentlyRunningItem` viewmodel accordingly. The dispatcher from the UI thread is passed in as a parameter so the event updates can be handled back on the UI thread.

**The problem is:** there is a race condition. The event for "All Complete" is invoked on the UI thread dispatcher, but then immediately after the await yields control back to the calling method, the finally block is hit and sets the current item to null, and then the `OnUpdateEvent` event handler will throw an exception trying to use the null current item field.

[The MSDN docs for Dispatcher.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) claims it "*Executes the specified delegate synchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.*" This does not align with my experience above, where it seems to invoke the delegate asynchronously and return before my eventhandler method is called. I have also tried using `SyncronisationContext.Send()` instead of the dispatcher, with the exact same result.

I'm starting to pull hairs here. Either Ι'm completely misunderstanding the meaning of "synchronous" or Ι'm doing something horribly wrong. How can I fix this problem and ensure the program executes the way I want it to, or is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** The race condition was solved by removing the ".ConfigureAwait(false)" from the RunNextItem() method. I don't have a complete understanding of what was happening under the hood, but it seems that this was allowing immediate continuation on a different thread than the event handlers which in turn caused the race condition.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better solution than this?

Absolutely. There's a [standard progress pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#progress-reporting-optional) that simplifies this considerably:

```
public class DemoViewModel
{
  private DemoRunClass DemoRunner;

  public async Task RunNextItem()
  {
    // get viewmodel of next item and create a command for it.
    var nextRunnableItemViewModel = GetNextItem();
    var runItemCommand = GenerateCommand(nextRunnableItemViewModel);

    var progress = new Progress<string>(status =>
    {
        if (status == "Method1 complete")
            nextRunnableItemViewModel.OnMethod1Complete();
        // ...
        else if (status == "All Complete")
            nextRunnableItemViewModel.OnAllComplete();
    });
    await Task.Run(() => DemoRunner.ExecuteLongRunningTask(runItemCommand, progress));
  }
}

public class DemoRunClass
{
  public Task ExecuteLongRunningTask(object command, IProgress<string> progress)
  {
    Method1(progress); // call progress?.Report(method 1 complete)
    Method2(progress); // call progress?.Report(method 2 complete).. etc
    Method3(progress);
    Method4(progress);
    Method5(progress);
    progress?.Report("All Complete");
  }

  private void Method1(IProgress<string> progress)
  {
    // do some work ..
    progress?.Report("Method1 complete");
  }
}
```

Notes:

- [Use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (as explained on my blog).
- [Use `Task.Run` in the invocation, not as the implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) (as explained on my blog).
- `Progress<T>` captures the current `SynchronizationContext` for you (which in this case captures the current `Dispatcher`).

Comment: Hi @Stephen Cleary,  I am honored you have answered my SO question, love your blogs. The reason I used Task.Factory instead of Task.New is because some of the internal methods in the execution step are actually also concurrent and creating their own child tasks, and I needed to specify these were attached to parent, in order for exceptions to be correctly handled by the try/catch around the invocation. Not doing so gave me unhandled task exceptions. I will look into the progress event, but I notice you removed the try/catch in the RunNextItem() method. Was this an intentional omission?

Comment: @user2790954: You shouldn't mix parent tasks with `await`; you will see surprising results. As long as all your child tasks are properly `await`ed, exceptions should flow naturally. I removed the try/finally because there's no longer a local variable that needs to be cleared; if you have important code in the catch, just add it back in.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on what you mean by mix parent tasks with await? In my case I have the parent task created by the invocation of the LongRunningTask. There is a child task created within the execution of that method that is awaited. Basically:

await Method1(); // synchronous,returns task.CompletedTask
await Method2(); // async, returns Task.Factory.StartNew().
.. etc

Comment: @user2790954: Awaiting a method is fine (although you should avoid `StartNew`). What I said about parent tasks refers to tasks that are "attached to parent", which you mentioned above you were using. That's going to cause even more problems; attached child tasks shouldn't ever be necessary in async/await code.